# I have one custom text box , I have set predefined value i.e (value = "sa") of text box now field is not editabl c#?

Tags: c#

Do we have any property when we enter custom textbox value then it will be also editable on docusign.

Please help me on this.

Comment: On docusign library

Comment: Please share you xaml.

Comment: I am doing this on  using Docusign library on c#.

Comment: control = new tbleAppsComboSHIDocuSignControlDetailsBK
            {
                AnchorTabString = AnchorTabStringAgentComments,
                TabLabel = DocuSignControlTabLabelAgentComment,
                XOffset = 200,
                YOffset = -10,
                Name =DocuSignControlNameCommentOrNA,
                PageNumber = 1,
                RecipientID = 2,
                Type = DocuSignCustomControlType,
                Isrequired = 1,
                MaxWidth = 350, MaxHeight = 200, IsLocked = 0, DocumentID = 2,